# Can I change the default media player on Pumpkin Android 11 radio?

Tags: default-applications, media-player, usb-peripherals, automotive-head-unit

I have a USB disk with MP3 music connected. Everytime when the Pumpkin radio has booted, it recognizes the USB disk and starts the preinstalled media player automatically, which starts playing the first song from the disk. This is annoying, and furthermore, I'm not satisfied with this app cause it lacks relevant features.

I want that the media player "Phonograph", which I have installed, starts instead. I have asked Pumpkin support, they say it is not possible to change the default media player app. I have looked in the settings "**Apps -> Standard apps**", but there is no setting for the topic "Mediaplayer" available (there is a setting for the default browser and one other topic, only)
I tried to disable this default player app (I forgot the name) but not possible, is greyed out.

Does anyone have an idea? If possible, without root.
Thank you.